# ldd doesn't show dynamic libraries

Tags: gdb, libraries, dynamic-linking

I'm trying understand how some parts of a closed source program distributed as a stripped binary implemented. When I run `ldd` on the program, it prints only 4-5 most basic C libraries as dynamic dependencies. (e.g. `libc`, `glib`, `gobject` etc.) However, when I run it in gdb or attach gdb to it and run `info sharedlibrary`, it prints a huge list of libraries. Indeed, that program clearly uses GTK for GUI, for example, but gtk libraries are missing in `ldd` output and shown in `info sharedlibrary` output.

I was wondering does it work and how did they achieve this. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can load their dynamic libraries dynamically by using `dlopen` and `dlsym` functions.
Here is the [man page of dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) and [usage example](http://christopherpoole.github.io/dynamically-linking-shared-objects-in-c++/)

Comment: You're definitely correct, I set breakpoints on `dlopen` and `dlsym`, and it stopped at `dlopen`. When I `print (char*) $rdi` it printed "libcairo.so". Now, my question is, why would they do that? Those libraries export huge number of symbols, are they manually linking all of them? Any ideas why would I want this?

Comment: They probably do it for cross-platform compatibility reasons.